# TypeScript Erorr: Output file has not been built from source file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I have a TypeScript project where I want to import a module but I am getting this error

> Output file 'electron/types/AppFrameName.d.ts' has not been built from source file 'electron/types/AppFrameName.ts'.ts(6305)

But the crazy thing is that if I delete the `src/App.vue` file or if I delete the `electron/types/AppFrame.ts` file then the error goes away. I don't understand what kind of TypeScript magic is this?

[image]

Here is a repo with the full code: https://github.com/martinszeltins/typescript-error

I have a very basic TypeScript project. Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "strict": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"],
            "@electron/*": ["./electron/*"]
        },
    },
    "references": [
        { "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }
    ],
    "include": [
        "electron/types/AppFrame.ts",
        "electron/types/AppFrameName.ts",
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.d.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "src/**/*.vue",
        "components.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

and here is `tsconfig.node.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },

    "include": ["vite.config.ts", "package.json", "electron", "electron/**/*.ts",]
}
```

Then in my `main.ts` file I have this import and an error:

```
import AppFrameName from '@electron/types/AppFrameName'
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                          Output file 'electron/types/AppFrameName.d.ts' has not been built from source file 'electron/types/AppFrameName.ts'.ts(6305)


const myFunction = (name: AppFrameName) => {
    return name.toLowerCase()
}

myFunction('aaaa')
```